# Book series with the first book having a very pretty mystical girl in fog

Tags: story-identification, books

I checked out a book half a year ago, and because chrome doesn't remember history past 90 days and the library has no records due to privacy concerns, I can't seem to find back that book.

All I know is that:

- The book is a series
- The first book's cover has a pretty, ghostly white girl shrouded in fog
- The book is a Red Dot book

Any help?

Comment: Have a look at our [helpful checklist for story-identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and see if there's anything perhaps you remember that you could [edit] in to your question. No detail is too small

Comment: Same as [these Red Dot books](https://www.goodreads.com/list/tag/red-dot)?